# Best way to migrate to Azure

Tags: .net, sql, azure, asmx, azure-sql-database

I am new to windows Azure and it is very interesting to me, but I have some questions about it. I am having web site (aspx) and my db is SQL server 2008. There are also one .NET windows service and asmx page.

What is the best option to host it on Azure and pay less? Is it possible to put my whole Windows 7 OS with those apps as a virtual machine and access my web site (aspx) pages normally (via IP)? Is this better (cheaper) option than to migrate my apps and DB directly do Azure? I still do not know how often will be used this enviroment, and if somebody could explain me how is it calculated.

Thanks, 
Nikola

Comment: The best way to reduce cost on Azure (and other cloud provider) is to build optimized apps, that requires less possible access to the DB, as its often the most expensive part. You may read about some very interesting design patterns like CQRS, especially interesting on cloud platforms, as you can have a "local" read model wich can be a simple file. More on this on [Lokad.CQRS](http://lokad.github.com/lokad-cqrs/) which is one of the most know CQRS framework

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is very broad in scope and more than you could possibly hope to get a meaningful answer here - It sounds like your setup is complex.  Your best bet is to check out the pricing and come to your own conclusions.

[Pricing Calculator](http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/pricing/calculator/)

Answer (score 0):

Azure pricing calculator is available [**here**](http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/pricing/calculator/).

Azure pricing is explained [**here**](http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/pricing/details/)

You might want to check if you're eligible for a year free with WebSiteSpark program.
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/windowsazure/archive/2012/06/20/announcing-one-year-of-windows-azure-free-with-websitespark.aspx